# Using paramiko more than one time in a script

Tags: python, paramiko

I am creating a script that uses different commands in different servers... To do it, I avoid to use tools like sshpass, and I try to do it by using **paramiko** (because with paramiko, I can handle exceptions and I can also exit the ssh session).

There are two machines that I must connect to, there are two different commands to use, etc.

The problem is, that I would like to not repeat the code I use twice, my code is something like:

```
    try:
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        ssh_client.connect(args.ip, username=args.user,
                           port=port,
                           password=args.pwd,
                           timeout=connect_timeout,
                           allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (args.ip, str(e))
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command)
        commandStatus = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
        output = stdout.read()
        commandError = stderr.read()
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Failed to execute command "%s": %s' % (command, str(e))

    if commandError:
        print 'Command failed: %s' % (commandError)
        sys.exit(2)



    try:
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        ssh_client.connect(args.ip2, username=args.user2,
                           port=port,
                           password=args.pwd2,
                           timeout=connect_timeout,
                           allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (args.ip2, str(e))
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command2)
        commandStatus = stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
        output = stdout.read()
        commandError = stderr.read()
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Failed to execute command "%s": %s' % (command2, str(e))

    if commandError:
        print 'Command failed: %s' % (commandError)
        sys.exit(2)
```

Is it possible to do it just using that code once?

Comment: Can you add the remaining code, that populates args and how command is populated?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but have you looked at [fabric](https://www.fabfile.org/)? It is designed for what it sounds like you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the smallest element of code re-use is the function. So, make a function for creating the connection, for instance.

```py
def connect(user, pass, hostname, port):
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        ssh_client.connect(hostname, username=user,
                           port=port,
                           password=pass,
                           timeout=connect_timeout,
                           allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)
        return ssh_client

# then use the code, for instance
try:
        client_a = connect('admin', 'secret', 'myhost.com', 22)
        client_b = connect('notadmin', 'notsecret', 'otherhost.com', 22222) 
except SomeException: # it's a bad idea to use plain Except 
        print('message')
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: But how could I pass the rest of the variables? Password for the second host, user for the second...

Comment: Add more function arguments like
```python
client_a = connect('myhost.com', 'user', 'password')
client_b = connect('otherhost.com', 'otheruser', 'secret')
```

Comment: Can you add it in the answer? So I can vote